# Is there something like __LINE__ in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am new to Verilog but have been a C programmer for years which makes me dangerous.

I'm doing some Verilog for a class. I'd like to use C assert() style testing in my simulation code. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h

We aren't using System Verilog so there is no standard assert that I could find. I have cobbled together the following macro.

```
`define ASSERT_EQUALS(x,y) \
    repeat(1)\
    begin\
        if( (x) != (y) ) \
        begin\
            $write( "assert failed %d != %d\n", (x), (y) );\
            $finish;\
        end\
    end 

    // test the assert( should fail)
    `ASSERT_EQUALS(t_data_in,16'hfffe)
```

As far as I can tell there is no way to get a line number. So if the assertion fails, I only get a message with no way to link back to the location of the failure.

```
assert failed 65535 != 65534
```

Is there a way to get the current line number? Or is there a better way to do an assertion test in Verilog?

Thanks!

Comment: SystemVerilog also has native support for assertions.

Comment: Icarus Verilog supports `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` macros after iverilog version 1.0 see test case [ivltests/fileline.v](https://github.com/steveicarus/ivtest/blob/master/ivltests/fileline.v) for usage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a procedural context you can use  `$finish(1);` which should print the location.

Comment: Tested in Icarus Verilog. That parameter to $finish() isn't implemented. However does work in Xilinx. I'll see if I can submit a fix for Icarus Verilog. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

SystemVerilog 2009 offers compiler directives. Quoting from the specification IEEE Std 1800-2009, Section 22.13:

> `` `__FILE__ `` expands to the name of the current input file, in the form of a string literal. This is the path by which a tool opened the file, not the short name specified in `` `include `` or as a tool’s input file name argument. The format of this path name may be implementation dependent.
>
>
> `` `__LINE__ `` expands to the current input line number, in the form of a simple decimal number.

> For example:
> `` $display("Internal error: null handle at %s, line %d.", `__FILE__, `__LINE__); ``

Refer to the full specification for more details.